# How would you make this layout in materialize or css-grid?

Tags: html, css

how would you make a layout like this using css-grid or materialize?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I guess this is what you want.

```
.grid-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 25% 73%;
 grid-gap: 10px;
 background-color: #2196F3;
 padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container > div {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.item1,.item2,.item3,.item4
{
height:150px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="item1">1</div>
<div class="item2">2</div>
<div class="item3">3</div>  
<div class="item4">4</div>
</div>
```

Try this w3schools tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick example of how it can be done using a grid. Hope it helps.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```